# Compare date of datetime object in filter django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I use django 3.1.0

I have a release_time field(a DateTimeFeild) in my model, and i want to retrieve those records that have been released in current date.

here is my model:

```
class Test(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  release_time = models.DateTimeField()
  end_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

this is my time settings:

```
 TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tehran'

 USE_I18N = True

 USE_L10N = True

 USE_TZ = True
```

I use the following line to get my data:

```
cur_time = localtime() // django.utils.timezone.localtime
Test.objects.filter(release_time__date=cur_time.date())
```

This always returns an empty query set. I am sure that there are records that have this condition.

PLease tell me am I doing this wrong??

UPDATE

This is the WHERE statement in sql query.(the date is right and there is a record in the database with this date.

```
WHERE DATE(CONVERT_TZ(`contests_test`.`release_time`, 'Asia/Tehran', 'Asia/Tehran')) = 2020-11-23
```

If i use this query:

```
Test.objects.filter(release_time__date=TruncDate(Now()))
```

I get this sql:

```
WHERE DATE(CONVERT_TZ(`contests_test`.`release_time`, 'UTC', 'Asia/Tehran')) = DATE(CONVERT_TZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'UTC', 'Asia/Tehran'))
```

None of the above doesn't work.

I found a logical work around and I don't depend on this query anymore but this really keeps me awake at nights!!

Answer (score 0):

For getting current date for ORM usage purposes, you may use Django's database functions [Now()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#now) and truncate it to date using [DateTrunc()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncDate). This forces usage of database time in the query and also avoids mess with timezones in database and python sides. For example if `USE_TZ` setting is set to `False`, `.localtime()` will fail with error `ValueError: localtime() cannot be applied to a naive datetime`.

So you may try:

```
Test.objects.filter(release_time__date = TruncDate(Now()))
```

As for your query, I can't guess why it does not return data, it is well formed and should be fetching the result. So, it is always a good practice to see what actual sql is executed by Django, by using `.query`.

Please, execute the following and look at where clause part of the sql statement, it may contain additional hints, like different timezones or whatsoever.

```
q = Test.objects.filter(
    release_time__date=TruncDate( #django.db.models.functions.datetime.TruncDate
        Now() # django.db.models.functions.datetime.Now
    )
)
print(q.query)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and your useful tip. Although I couldn't solve my proablem.